# Why isn't Autohotkey script executing after reboot/restart?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this hotkey script:

```
; F7 key by default, Fn+F7 does nothing
^#F21::
SendInput {Volume_Up}
return
```

I ran it yesterday and it seemed to work well. However, today I turned on my PC and it was being executed, but it wasn't responding to my inputs. I reloaded it, but same result: executing, but not responding to inputs.

How can I solve it?

Comment: do you have an F21 key? did you mean F12?  the F12 key on my Mac is Volume Up 
 which is why I ask. Maybe look into using SoundGet and SoundSet commands.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "not responding to inputs". If the script is running it shall react to the hotkey. Restart has no effect here on a change of behavior (if the script is running). Maybe debug with a MsgBox to see if your hotkey is triggered.